# Twitter widget does not scroll WITH the page on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, scroll

I'm sure a lot of people use the twitter widget that twitter provides.

Here's the code twitter provides:

```
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script> 
<script> 
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 3,
  interval: 6000,
  width: 420,
  height: 250,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#000000'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#000000',
      links: '#666666'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: false,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: false,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('apumpkinpatch').start();
</script>
```

You can see an example here that while using IE the site updates (the twitter widget) doesn't scroll with the page while using IE: http://apumpkinpatch.com/

EDIT:
I on IE7, for some reason there are two vertical scrollbars and It appears under all the other content now after i played with the z index... I can't explain the double scrollbars on IE it's really weird. I'm typically a mac user so i dont know what the double vertical scrollbars are about

I think the class for the widget is .twtr-doc according to the inspector. Anyone know if there is a css attribute I should be adding to it to stop this from happening in IE?

Works fine in CHrome and FF.

Comment: Did you see my solution below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double scroll lines appear because the `body` container is set to `overflow:auto`. If you remove that rule only the window will scroll now.

However the layout issues that then follow after you make this fix, are inside the iframe code and so not editable by you.

Comment: Ah thanks! I thought that was nessissary to allow the page to scroll. But it works just fine without it and it fixed the double bars on IE. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. Please could you vote the answer up as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine in my IE.
Im using v8.

Comment: I on IE7, for some reason there are two vertical scrollbars and It appears under all the other content now after i played with the z index... I can't explain the double scrollbars on IE it's really weird. I'm typically a mac user so i dont know what the double vertical scrollbars are about